# Fill a text box while selected Auto Complete

Tags: jquery, html

How do i fill " hello world " into " # fill " box while I select the autocomplete option in " # autocomplete " box.

HTML :

```
<input id="autocomplete" type="text">
<input id="fill" type="text">
```

Jquery :

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source : autocomplete_Source
});
```

Comment: You can use [Select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
      $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: autocomplete_Source,
        select: function (event, ui) {
           $("#fill").val("Hello World")
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {


        },
        open: function (event, ui) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: @R. Shilesh Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vrczuq1/1/)

The below script will automatically fill the textfield with id `fill` **with the selected value from the autocomplete**.

**Javascript**

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: autocomplete_Source,
  close: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#fill').val($( "#autocomplete" ).val());
  }
});
```

You can use the `close` event for this. See more about the events in the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event).